# Making nginx check parameter in url

Tags: nginx, parameters, arguments

I want to check if a parameter is present in a url in nginx and then rewrite.How can i do that?

For e.g if url is `http://website.com/?mobile` then redirect user to `http://m.website.com`

Comment: Try to use some value if you could. Checking that parameter has some value is simple `if ($arg_mobile)`. Checking if there is empty argument `mobile` is not so clear and error-prone.

Comment: @AlexeyTen could you post it as an answer with an example...i never worked with arguments before

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You better use `http://example.com/?mobile=1` (argument with value). In this case checking is simple:

```
if ($arg_mobile) {
    return 302 http://m.example.com/;
}
```

Checking for argument existance is usually done with regexp like `if ($args ~ mobile)` but it's error-prone, because it will match `mobile` anywhere, e.g. `http://example.com/?tag=automobile`.

Comment: All i need to do is add the code above to my nginx conf.Does nginx already know that `$arg_mobile` will check for `?mobile-1`.

Comment: (=) — equality sign, not (-) hyphen. It will check for `mobile=pretty-anything` except `0` (zero) and empty argument.

Comment: i'm getting nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($arg_querystringkey)" for version nginx/1.12.2. Is this not supported any more?

Comment: @raksja try to add space after “if”

Comment: thanks @AlexeyTen, it worked. I have a followup question on dynamic proxy_pass variable in here, can you pls take a look [nginx dynamic proxy pass variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417473/nginx-dynamic-proxy-pass-with-variable-between-redirections)

Comment: thanks, way defined to get the arguments value helped me i.e. $arg_mobile

Comment: similarly, but I can't get it to work. http://example.com/script.php?1234 I've followed the above example, and maybe numeric characters are different, but if ($arg_123) is not working like i might expect from the accepted answer. any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you know you have only 1 parameter `{{variable}}` to switch, you can detect if exist like this

```
if ($request_uri ~ '\?{{variable}}') {
    ...
}
```

for example

```
if ($request_uri ~ '\?mobile') {
    return 302 https://m.example.com;
}
```

Also I suggest consider use this redirection

`http://{{domain}}.{{tld}}/mobile` -> `http://m.{{domain}}.{{tld}}`

```
location ~ '/mobile'
    return 301 'https://m.{{domain}}.{{tld}}';
}
```

for example

```
location ~ '/mobile'
    return 301 'https://m.example.com';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to match your param

```
if ($args ~ '\bmobile[=&]?' )
{
    return 302 http://m.example.com/;
}
```

as this will match 'mobile' anywhere in $args, with or without value.